# building boost with visual studio 2012, what to provide as toolset?

Tags: boost

1. When building boost using Visual studio 2012 what should I provide as toolset?

   - msvc-10.0
   - msvc-11.0 (does it exist?)
   - msvc (autodetect?)
2. What would be recommended string to build boost x64 with Visual studio 2012?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

asking my question myself. providing `msvc` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have been involved in programming a graphical tool that builds boost for you: http://vertexwahn.de/bluego.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `bootstrap; b2` which will automatically choose for you. Refer to boost installation guide.

[Building boost on Windows](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#id37)

Comment: i'm using these instructions and `bjam` is not mentioned here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source

Comment: Then I believe it should be as simple as `bootstrap; b2`. I might have missed something, but I recall that being really simple